# All bootstrap navbars appear at the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to HTML/CSS and my bootstrap navbars appear at the center for some reason and I cannot move it.

Well, I can use nav-brand, but what it does I moves the text only. It also has `bg-light` which I don't know how to move. Any help? (sorry for stupid question)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: move it to the right

Comment: What do you want to move right

Answer (score 0):

***Hi i have fixed nav items to right please check***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>Facebook Login</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
     integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
     crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    .navRight {
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <main>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
       target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navRight" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data- 
            toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </main>
    </body>

    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

and [check out my stackblitz for the preview](https://html-basics-ubxr2o.stackblitz.io)